# SQL select in 1 line

Tags: abap, opensql

I have a table with the below data

| route | abnum | knanf | knend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00012 | 1 | PI | SY |
| 00012 | 2 | SY | PA |
| 00012 | 3 | PA | HN |

and the query

```sql
select knanf as start, knend as end from TVRAB as a
where route = '00012' and
  ( abnum = ( select min( ABNUM ) from TVRAB where route = a~route ) or
    abnum = ( select max( ABNUM ) from TVRAB where route = a~route ) )
```

The results are 2 lines

| START | END |
| --- | --- |
| PI | SY |
| PA | HN |

Can we have in 1 line the MIN `KNANF` and the MAX `KNEND` e.g.

| START | END |
| --- | --- |
| PI | HN |

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Below query produces the output you are looking for.

```
  SELECT a1~knanf AS start, a2~knend AS end FROM tvrab AS a1
   INNER JOIN tvrab AS a2
  ON a1~route = a2~route
  WHERE a1~route = '00012'
  AND a1~abnum = ( SELECT MIN( abnum ) FROM tvrab WHERE route = a1~route )
  AND a2~abnum = ( SELECT MAX( abnum ) FROM tvrab WHERE route = a1~route )
```